# Client configuration zookeeper.znode.rootserver

Tags: hbase, cloudera

I use a VM whose zookeeper.znode.rootserver Cloudera is not the default for the version of HBase ( 0.98 ) .

When I try to connect to HBase , my java client does not affect me the value of zookeeper.znode.rootserver.

```
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "hbaseip");
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase");
conf.set("zookeeper.znode.rootserver", "root-region-server");

HTable table = new HTable(conf, "mytable");
table.exists(new Get(Bytes.toBytes("test")));
```

Or with hbase-site.xml :

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>hbaseip</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
    <value>/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>zookeeper.znode.rootserver</name>
    <value>root-region-server</value>
</property>
```

When i launch, i have :

```
connection-0x1dcbdd11-0x148cd2220550084, quorum=hbaseip:2181, baseZNode=/hbase 
Unable to get data of znode /hbase/meta-region-server because node does not exist (not an error)
```

Thanks  ...

Comment: Did you fix the problem?